# Error when Adding Wordpress to Smarty Engine

Tags: wordpress, smarty

I keep getting this error when I try to add wp-blog-header into my smarty template does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is the code im using.

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/home/gorilla/public_html/wp-blog-header.php'); 
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

And here is the error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wptexturize() (previously declared in /home/gorilla/public_html/community/common/formatting.php:2) in /home/gorilla/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 99
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you write your own wptexturize function om common/formatting.php? That this could be the issue.